# I'm seafarer and I have iceland issued schengen visa, can use this to visit my girlfriend in netherland?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am a seafarer and im on vacation now, and I have a schengen visa, I want to visit my girlfriend in netherlands. Can i use my schengen visa which is valid for 90 days and has multiple entry on it?

Comment: Have you already used the visa to visit Iceland? In general, once you've used a multi-entry Schengen visa for the destination you specified when you got it, it's good for anywhere in Schengen on subsequent trips.

Comment: Yah, I used it, because i was joined in reyjavik iceland, but i only stayed there for 1 day.

Comment: Do you think i can still use it in going to netherland?

Comment: We receive this question so frequently that we designated a question and answer for everyone who has the same question.